# how to goback when use custom error page in webview android?

Tags: android, webview

I try to implement going back when pressing back key if there is previous pages exist. I also use a custom error Html page. But i found using goback will load the previous error html, how should i do to fix ? thanks

```
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                    String description, String failingUrl) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);

            requestLink = failingUrl;

            try {
                mWebView.stopLoading();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(FLAG, e.toString());
            }
            try {
                mWebView.clearView();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(FLAG, e.toString());
            }


            mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/net_err.html");
            mWebView.invalidate();
        }
```

and the code used to goback

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();

            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

and the code to refresh, called by js in error html.

```
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void refreshPage(){
        mWebView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mWebView.loadUrl(requestLink);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: At last, I implement error page in Android layout file, and setVisible when errors occur

Answer (score 0):

Try this

@Override

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

```
if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
    if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
     if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
           mWebView.goBack();

        return true;
    }
  }
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
```

}

Comment: thanks for reply, but this may have some problems when no error happened like PageA->PageB->PageC, C will go back to A

Comment: Check your mWebView url if it is your custom error page url then do like it.otherwise simple as it